# Laravel assets folder and bootstrap

Tags: laravel

I have started my first laravel project after I got a recommendation to use a framework.

I have started watching some tutorials and am trying to follow along, but in all the tutorials there is an assets folder inside resources with for example a `_variables` file. I don't have this folder, I guess it because I am using laravel version 7x and the tutorials are using an older version? I also thought bootstrap was provided with laravel, but it does not work. Have I done anything wrong or does everything seem right? I have followed a tutorial step-by-step from the start and used `npm install` & `npm run dev`, but the css file it creates is empty. I have also tried to start over with a new project, but the same happens!
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you already run `composer require laravel/ui`? Laravel 7 has frontend scaffolding. You can read the documentation's about frontend scaffolding here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend.
Hope this help.

Comment: It worked. I reinstalled node.js and it worked like it should after I used your command.

Comment: Glad to help you bro.